# software update interrupted and audio driver not working

Tags: drivers, sound, updates

I tried to update my software from the software center , but it failed and the next day I am unable to install any apps from software center or `apt-get` command. Mine is Ubuntu 16.04 and

```
uname -a
Linux prem 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Here is the error
sudo apt-get install update
sudo: unable to resolve host prem
[sudo] password for premkr: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

My audio is not working either.Can someone please help me?

*Edited: Kindly brief more on this questions as much as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```